# Is there a manager for creases or edge groups for Blender 2.8?

Tags: modeling, mesh

For a lot of subd models with creases I need a crease-**editor** like Maya have.

In Blender all edges must be manually selected to tweak or adjust the values one by one  by hand. In version 2.8 it's getting  dangerous after 8 hours of selecting and writing down with the annotate tool my clickfinger hurtS.
sometimes specialIy after hours I move acidently the edges just a tiny little bit when selecting a edge check the creasing value and then the shading can look wrong,maybe  the face is not planar anymore, its now distorted and now the model look like a error and must  unwraped  UV again.
Urrghhhh...
Is there an add-on for Blender 2.8 that could help with that Problem and bring a  creases manager in my Pipeline like Maya have .

One help would be that selecting with rightclick can't move the edge with a mouse move without gizmo is involved.
A click and drag on  the White gizmo Ring schould move the edge or vertex .but

How to Setup the preference keymap.? I Don t know..

For a decade Maya has this tool but in Blender 2.8 I could not find an **edge-group-manager**.
Is there anything in development, or is there another free tool that has edge Group creases Management?
 Here a link anyone can look how the creases manager Editor works..

https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2018/ENU/Maya-Modeling/files/GUID-83308C84-E5EE-4B07-8B26-7C04F8134701-htm.html

Cool festures f.e.you can choose your color s for different crease , the creases are  listed named with  values that can be tweaked without selecting again and  again edges or edg loops to see the values.

so simple Mega cool ...

Comment: Hello and welcome :). Why not just use multiple [vertex groups](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/properties/vertex_groups/introduction.html) for easy management of your edges?

Comment: Thx...I need the creases  values from the whol model without selecting and selecting it again and again .my work since days is to  bring down  the creases values down .

Comment: Right. I believe vertex groups are as close as you'll get. You can select all vertices inside a vertex group by one click, so it's at least something :). Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You can select one creased edge, then use Shift G "select similar, crease" , then assign them to a vertex group for faster selection.

[image]

Comment: Yeah thx i try it AT morning but the values to tweak togehter in a List I miss...

Comment: Mantain pressed pressed Alt key while entering a new value on multi selection.

Comment: Thx real cool and fast.